# React: How to display Firestore subcollection

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

Have trouble fetching Firestore sub-collection. As an image shows, document field containing `name` and `label` are in `timezone` sub-collection in Firestore. I want to show `timezone.label` in Profile page. But it's not working.

Not working:

```
user.timezone.label
user.timezone['label']
```

console

```
timezone 
{label: "Phoenix (MST)", value: "America/Phoenix"}
label: "Phoenix (MST)"
value: "America/Phoenix"
__proto__: Object
```

[image]

How can I display `timezone label` in Profile page.

Answer (score 0):

Looking and the screenshot `timezone` is for sure not sub-collection, but document field in type of map and of course getting data from map is supported by Firestore database.

I don't know how do you create the connection to the database, but lets assume that `firestore` is instance of Firestore database:

So first you have to get the `documentSnapshot` from `documentReference` ex.:

```
const collection = firestore.collection(<collections_users_name>);
const userRefence = col.doc(<user_doc>).get();
```

Than you can get documentSnapshot like this:

```
user.then(user_snapshot => console.log(
    user_snapshot.data().timezone.label
);
```

You can use [this](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data) and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore) as reference. Good Luck!